# Query for the following out put from the given image

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a output in following ways...

the table name is exampackage

**select * from exampackage where pname='medical' and ptype like '%neurology%' order by pprice asc**  this query i have used but it is giving me only one subject output i want all subjects output.

```
**Free Cardiology Pack(2 Papers Accessible-1 Internal Medicine + 1 Cardiology)
Cardiology Mini Pack (20 Papers) - 2900 RS
Cardiology Mega Pack (43 Papers) - 4900 RS**

**Free Neurology Pack (2 Papers Accessible-1 Internal Medicine + 1 Neurology)
Neurology Mini Pack (15 papers) - 3900 RS
Neurology Mega Pack(40 Papers)-4900 RS**

and so on....
```

Please help me out

[image: Click here to view the image]

Comment: Please provide sample data as text, so we can play around with it. Same goes for expected output.

Comment: Select ptype from (table_name) ???

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a "free coding service".

Comment: Perhaps this will help you provide your data in a **consumable** format: [Forum Etiquette: How to post Sample Data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from (
select *,'neurology' as psubject from exampackage where ptype like '%neurology%'
Union all
select *,'cardiology' as psubject from exampackage where ptype like '%cardiology%'
Union all
Select * from...... With different subject in where clause
)a  where a.pname='medical' order by psubject, pprice
```

Hope this helps...